# Scheduled Reports: is there an archive or log?

Tags: reporting, scheduled-job, scheduled

Can I see which reports were sent via report scheduler after the fact? Is there a "sent" folder where I can see the html content of what sent?

Comment: not that i know of; others may no better.  But you could add a "logging" user to every scheduled report and have that user receive a copy of the report - their inbox becomes the log